# Mysql_stmt::bind_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, subquery

I have the following mysql query which am executing in my php script:

```
$qr = "Select p.productID,p.productDesc,p.productQty,";
$qr .= "p.productPr,p.type,p.gender,p.date From";
$qr .= " products AS p";
$qr .= " INNER JOIN(Select c.productID, GROUP_CONCAT(";
$qr .= "DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list FROM";
$qr .= " availColors AS c GROUP BY c.productID) AS colors";
$qr .= " ON p.productID = colors.productID":
$qr .= " INNER JOIN(SELECT s.productID, GROUP_CONCAT";
$qr .= "(s.availSizes) AS size_list FROM availSizes AS s";
$qr .= " GROUP BY s.productID) AS sizes ON p.productID";
$qr .= " = sizes.productID";
$qr .= " INNER JOIN(SELECT avp.productID, avp.productImg";
$qr .= " FROM availImg AS avp ORDER BY avp.productID";
$qr .= " LIMIT 3) AS images ON images.productID = ";
$qr .= " p.productID";
$qr .= " WHERE p.productID = ?";
$qr .= " GROUP BY p.productID";

$stm = $mysqli->prepare($qr);
$stm->bind_param('s',$id);
$stm->execute();
$stm->store_result();

If($stm->num_rows == 1){
$stm->bind_result($pid,$desc,$qty,$pr,$type,$gender,
$date,$colID,$color,$sizeID,$sizes,$imgID,$imgUrl);

$stm->fetch();
......
}
```

When I execute the script I get an error saying: 
    Mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
    Match number of fields in the prepared statement in...

I understand what this error means, but I have rechecked and recounted the number of bind variables in the bind_result() against the number of SELECTed columns, I just can't figure out what is wrong. I don't know how PHP evaluates values returned from a mysql subquery. Can anyone offer help on this? I have been on this all day! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$qr = "
Select
    p.productID,
    p.productDesc,
    p.productQty,
    p.productPr,
    p.type,
    p.gender,
    p.date
From
    products AS p
    INNER JOIN(
        Select 
            c.productID, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list 
        FROM
            availColors AS c GROUP BY c.productID) AS colors
            ON
                p.productID = colors.productID
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT
                s.productID,
                GROUP_CONCAT(s.availSizes) AS size_list
            FROM
                availSizes AS s
            GROUP BY
                s.productID
        ) AS sizes
    ON
        p.productID = sizes.productID
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT
                avp.productID,
                avp.productImg
            FROM
                availImg AS avp
            ORDER BY
                avp.productID
            LIMIT
        3) AS images
    ON
        images.productID =  p.productID
WHERE
    p.productID = ?
GROUP BY
    p.productID";
```

Try formatting your query like this muti-line strings are perfectly fine in PHP, and it's almost impossible to make sense of it concatenated line by line.  If I have it right you are missing at least a closing parentheses in there, the first inner join open parentheses is not closed.

Comment: The multi-lines and closing parenthesis shouldn't be giving mysql_stmt::bind_result error. I don't see how what you've stated, connects with that error! I have taken note on the multiline stuff, thanks for that point though.

Comment: Besides if I have missed an open or close bracket, it must have been when I was typing this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are only joining your other tables/columns not selecting the columns. Try adding the columns to the beginning of the query (before the `FROM`)

```
$qr = "SELECT p.productID,p.productDesc,p.productQty,";
$qr .= "p.productPr,p.type,p.gender,p.date,";

// colors columns
$qr .= "colors.productID, colors.color_list,";
// sizes columns
$qr .= "sizes.productID, sizes.size_list,";
// images columns
$qr .= "images.productID, images.productImg ";

$qr .= "From products AS p";
$qr .= " INNER JOIN(Select c.productID, GROUP_CONCAT(";
$qr .= "DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list FROM";
$qr .= " availColors AS c GROUP BY c.productID) AS colors";
$qr .= " ON p.productID = colors.productID":
$qr .= " INNER JOIN(SELECT s.productID, GROUP_CONCAT";
$qr .= "(s.availSizes) AS size_list FROM availSizes AS s";
$qr .= " GROUP BY s.productID) AS sizes ON p.productID";
$qr .= " = sizes.productID";
$qr .= " INNER JOIN(SELECT avp.productID, avp.productImg";
$qr .= " FROM availImg AS avp ORDER BY avp.productID";
$qr .= " LIMIT 3) AS images ON images.productID = ";
$qr .= " p.productID";
$qr .= " WHERE p.productID = ?";
$qr .= " GROUP BY p.productID";
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean. It appears the LIMIT in INNER JOINS doesn't work?

Comment: The 'LIMIT 3' in the above query only returns one imageUrl for the selected ID! What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, thanks to MYSQL Workbench! I ran the query on mysql workbench and counted the number of columns returned, and declared variables for each on the bind_result().